# deserialize nested json object in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have json object in javascript as

```
{"CategoryID":"1","CountryID":"1","CountryName":"United Arab Emirates",
"BillerID":"23","AccountNo":"1234567890",
"Authenticators":"{\"ConsumerNumber\":\"1234567890\",\"LastBillDate\":\"14-10-2014\",\"LastBillDueDate\":\"24-11-2014\"}",
"ShortName":"0000000001"}
```

I have similar c# class as

```
[Serializable]
    public class UserContext
    {
        public string CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string BillerID { get; set; }
        public string AccountNo { get; set; }
        public string Authenticators { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string CountryID { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
```

I can get each element value in c# as

```
UserContext obj1 = Deserialize<UserContext>(context);
```

But as `Authenticators` is nested json object i want something like this in `C#`

```
[Serializable]
    public class Authenticators
    {
        public string ConsumerNumber { get; set; }
        public string LastBillDate { get; set; }
        public string LastBillDueDate { get; set; }
    }
```

So that i can get each value of each `Authenticators` element like

```
string value = obj.ConsumerNumber;
```

**I want to populate two classes with values. How can i achieve the same ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserContext class has a string field Authenticators, while the json structure suggests it's an object.

Change

```
public string Authenticators { get; set; }
```

to

```
public Authenticators Authenticators { get; set; }
```

Then you can deserialize the UserContext object along with the nested object Authenticators

```
UserContext obj1 = Deserialize<UserContext>(context);
var consumerNumber = obj1.Authenticators.ConsumerNumber;
```

UPDATE:

You probably need to fix javascript code, bacause now it stores already serialized json string as a string field inside UserContext object.

What you have now, is something similar to:

```
var data =
 {
   CategoryID:"1",
   Authenticators: JSON.stringify({ConsumerNumber:"1234567890"})
 };
 var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

It should be like:

```
var data =
 {
   CategoryID:"1",
   Authenticators:{ConsumerNumber:"1234567890"}
 };
 var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: How to extract `ConsumerNumber` then ?

Comment: It gives exception`Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyWebApplication.App_Code.Authenticators'` at line `UserContext obj1 = Deserialize<UserContext>(context1);`

Comment: This won't work. Authenticators is a string. The deserialization will not transform it to an object because the JSON is escaped.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy Thanks But One of my variable will require all three variable values in single i.e. `"{\"ConsumerNumber\":\"1234567890\",\"LastBillDate\":\"14-10-2014\",\"LastBillDueDate\":\"24-11-2014\"}"` in single variable. How can i get that value ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've deserialized the outer object, you can run another deserialize on the Authenticators JSON string, which is now a property on `obj1`.

This is required because your Authenticators is a *string*, it is escaped and thus can't be deserialized until the outer object is deserialized.

```
Authenticators obj2 = Deserialize<Authenticators>(obj1.Authenticators);
string value = obj2.ConsumerNumber;
```

Comment: What if my json string doesnt contain `Authenticators` ? Some error handling mechanism ?

Comment: You can add a condition before the second deserialization, to check if the Authenticators string contains a value: `if(obj1.Authenticators != ''){  }`. And you can use a try catch if you think the value might not always be a valid JSON string.

Comment: exception `Illegal characters in path.` while executing line `Authenticators obj2 = Deserialize<Authenticators>(obj1.Authenticators);`

Comment: Then your Authenticators string is not valid JSON. Try printing it out to see what it contains, after you deserialized the outer object.

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
public string Authenticators { get; set; }
```

to

```
public Authenticators Authenticators { get; set; }
```

then you can access the properties of the inner object simply by

```
var number = obj1.Authenticators.ConsumerNumber;
```

but i noticed that your JSON had some problems when deserializing using Newtonsoft, i had to change the value of Authenticators in the JSON string to

```
'Authenticators':{'ConsumerNumber':'1234567890','LastBillDate':'14-10-2014','LastBillDueDate':'24-11-2014'},
```

just remove the backslash

Comment: I am afraid that i can not change structure of json string in javascript !